# How to page break a PDF in swift

Tags: swift, pdf

I cant figure out how to create page breaks for the PDF I'm creating, I've tried a few different methods of creating the PDF and they all turn out the same. Im trying to create a PDF for a long multi-line label.

When I try to print only a string via UIActivityView it works perfectly with page breaks as you would expect. However when I attempt the PDF save or print it shows only one page in the print preview or when saving the PDF.

How do I include all my text in the PDF?

Here is my share function calling only the PDF right now for UIActivityView

```
 // Share function for share button
@objc func shareTapped() {
    
    // Create printable string
    let printableString = "Line measurement: \(sizeTransfer.text ?? "No data")\nCalculated size: \(heightSizeTransfer.text ?? "No data")\nHeight: \(heightTransfer.text ?? "No data")\n \nCoursing results:\n \n \(calcOutput.text ?? "No data")"
    
    // String print formatting
    let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
    let str = NSAttributedString(string: printableString, attributes: attrs)
    let print = (UISimpleTextPrintFormatter(attributedText: str))
    
    // Saving string file
    let tempDir = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
    let stringFileName = "Coursing Printout"
    let tempStringDir = tempDir.appendingPathComponent(stringFileName)
    try? printableString.write(to: tempDir, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    
    // Create PDF
    let pageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 612, height: 792)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: pageRect)
    let text = printableString
    let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)]
    let formattedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: textAttributes)
    let data = renderer.pdfData { ctx in
        ctx.beginPage()
        formattedText.draw(in: pageRect.insetBy(dx: 50, dy: 50))
    }
    
    // Give sharing functionality
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [data], applicationActivities: [])
    present(vc, animated: true)
    vc.excludedActivityTypes = [.assignToContact, .addToReadingList]
    
}
```

Comment: How do I do that? Ive read through much documentation and searched high and low but cant find a simple solution. Bear in mind I'm still pretty new to coding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this FINALLY after a week of searching!

This is the simplest and most definitive way to split a PDF!

https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/converting-attributed-string-to-pdf/

Comment: Please, write the relevant information here. Link only answers are useless.

Comment: Would that not be a sort of plagiarism where Im not giving credit to the source?

Comment: Nope. Plagiarising would be to copy paste the post here without change. Ideally, write a short answer in your own words. You can keep the link for details.

Comment: yea, this isn't a school assignment. its real life. just write the answer

Comment: Oops I forgot to get around to this, I’ll get it done tomorrow